# Python mock - Check if methods are called in mocked object

Tags: python, mocking, python-unittest

I have a certain piece of code that looks like this:

```
# file1.py
from module import Object

def method():
    o = Object("param1")
    o.do_something("param2")
```

I have unittests that look like this:

```
@patch("file1.Object")
class TestFile(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_call(self, obj):
        ...
```

I can do `obj.assert_called_with()` in the unittest to verify that the constructor was called with certain parameters. Is it possible to verify that `obj.do_something` was called with certain parameters? My instinct is no, as the Mock is fully encapsulated within Object, but I was hoping there might be some other way.

Comment: Did you try: `obj.do_something.assert_called_with()`?

Comment: I did try that. It says it was never called, which I believe is true since obj is a reference to the imported Object, and Object.do_something was never called.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this, because the arguments are passed to the mock object.
This should work:

```py
@patch("file1.Object")
class TestFile:
    def test_call(self, obj):
        method()
        obj.assert_called_once_with("param1")
        obj.return_value.do_something.assert_called_once_with("param2")
```

`obj.return_value` is the `Object` instance (which is a `MagickMock` object with the `Object` spec), and `do_something` is another mock in that object that is called with the given parameter.

As long as you are just passing arguments to mock objects, the mock will record this and you can check it. What you don't have is any side effects from the real function calls - so if the original `do_something` would call another function, this cannot be checked.

Comment: nice, this is it. The key part here is referencing obj.return_value, which I hadn't thought of.

Answer (score 0):

When you mock an object, it will mock the methods inside the object aswell. Therefore you are able to see if `obj.do_something` has been called with certain parameters as `obj.do_something.assert_called_with()`

For more information regarding unittest mocking can be found at the python library wiki https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html

A perfect example of what you are asking exist within that wiki source:

```
>>> mock = Mock()
>>> mock.method(1, 2, 3, test='wow')
<Mock name='mock.method()' id='...'>
>>> mock.method.assert_called_with(1, 2, 3, test='wow')
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.assert_called_with

Regards, I see that you placed the the patching on the object, try placing it on the function instead, like:

```
class TestFile(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch("file1.Object")
    def test_call(self, obj):
        ...
```

Comment: This doesn't work (says it was never called). I think this is because calling ```obj.do_something``` is equivalent to calling Object.do_something in file1, which doesn't happen.

Comment: Have you tried placing the patch at the test function instead of the class?